# Automatic results table for a problem set

Tags: programming

I have problem sets with multiple problems where each problem gives a different number of points. Some are bonus points, some are regular points. I'd like to show a table with each problem and the points, as well as a total (only non-bonus problems counted).

So far, I have just a simple table where I put in `\ref{1}`, `\ref{2}` and `Total`, and in the next line I have some `/ 10`, `/20` and `/20` written down. In each problem, which is a `\section`, I have `\label{1}` to mark then.

This does work, but I have the feeling that this could be automated. I would like to write something like `\points{20}` and `\points*{10}` after the sections, or maybe `\problem{problem title}{20}`. Then the table in the beginning of the document would automatically list all the problems and sum up all the non-bonus points and print the total into the last column.

Is that feasible or more work than just creating that table by hand?

Comment: Perhaps the [`exam`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) class could be an option for you.

Answer (score 3):

The [`exam`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/exam) `documentclass` is definitely worth considering for this task. It has a lot of features that help when constructing tests/exams/quizzes, which include

- `\question` to specify a question, which takes an optional numerical argument to detail the number of points, e.g `\question[10]` says that the question is worth `10` points
- `\gradetable` which keeps track of the questions and their point value
- `\part` to break the question in parts, which also takes an optional numerical argument (same as `\question`).

[image: screenshot]

I've put a complete MWE below- there are more features detailed in the [the documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/exam).

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}

% can use geometry package to set page sizes
\usepackage[left=2.25cm,right=2.25cm,
        top=0.5cm,
        bottom=1.0cm,
        footskip=0.5cm
        ]{geometry}

% can set headers and footers, similar 
% to fancyhdr package
\cfoot{\footnotesize Page \thepage {} of \numpages}
\lfoot{\footnotesize TOTAL POINTS \numpoints\ }
\rfoot{\footnotesize Exam 1}

\begin{document}

\pointsdroppedatright
\pointpoints{point}{points}

\extrawidth{0.5in}
\marginpointname{ \points}

% table of points
\gradetable

\bonusgradetable

\begin{questions}
    %+++++++++++++++++++++++++
    %   QUESTION
    %+++++++++++++++++++++++++
    \question
    Use the definition of the derivative to find $f'(x)$ for the following functions
    \begin{parts}
        \part[4] $f(x) = 2x^2 + 3$

        \vspace{\fill}
        \droppoints

        \part[4] $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{{x+3}}$

        \vspace{\fill}
        \droppoints

    \end{parts}

    \newpage
    %+++++++++++++++++++++++++
    %   QUESTION
    %+++++++++++++++++++++++++
    \bonusquestion
    Find the following limits. 

    \begin{parts}
        \bonuspart[4] $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 4}\frac{x^2-x-12}{x-4}$

        \vspace{\fill}
        \droppoints

        \part[4] $\displaystyle\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{4+h}-2}{h}$

        \vspace{\fill}
        \droppoints

        \part[4] $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{4x^3-x-2}{5x^3 + 4x +1}$

        \vspace{\fill}
        \droppoints

        \part[4] $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos\left(x-\pi\right)}{\cos(x)\sin(x)}$

        \vspace{\fill}
        \droppoints

    \end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```